# I'd like some advice on my inplementation of this finite algorithm

Tags: algorithms

I have this "while" statement and would like to know if is suitable form for a paper. Is there a better way to show this?
$$z(n):= \{\ 3^n-1+(--i)-2^ni\ |\ i=0; \text{ while } 2^n (1+i)<3^n+(i++)\ \}$$

Also, are pre-decrement and post-increment good form for a paper?

Comment: I have never seen a math (or cs) paper with a while loop inside a set construction. Parsing what you have written will be painful for your readers. Perhaps psuedocode would be acceptable in a cs paper. I suggest writing out the first few examples explicitly, then describing the general case either in words or with $\{ \text{foo} | 0 \le i  \le \text{bar}\}$ with an explicit representation for both the actual expression and  the upper limit. Avoid autoincrement and autodecrement at all costs.

Comment: @EthanBolker, This has no upper limit. It stops when the calculation is less than 2^n.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never seen a math (or cs) paper with a while loop inside a set construction. Parsing what you have written will be painful for your readers. Perhaps psuedocode would be acceptable in a cs paper. I suggest writing out the first few examples explicitly, then describing the general case either in words or with 
$$
z(n) = \{\text{foo}|0 \le  i \le \text{bar}\}
$$ 
with an actual expression in terms of $n$ and $i$ for foo.
Avoid autoincrement and autodecrement at all costs.

The upper limit can be specified as "where bar is the last value of $i$ for which $\text{foo} \le 2^n$".

Comment: +1 for the last sentence. Exactly what I needed, because I have several algorithms to describe.